# Referring to class attributes from the .kv file

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have the following related sections from my .py and .kv files.

```
class DrillScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DrillScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.thedrill = drill(kwargs['options'])
        self.thedrill.bind(on_answer = self.printtest)


    def printtest(self,*args):
        self.ids.answerlabel.text = self.thedrill.answer
        print(self.ids.answerlabel.text)

    def startdrill(self):
        Process(target=self.thedrill.run).start()
```

---

```
<DrillScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint: 1.0, None
            height: self.width
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
            id: wheelbox
            background_color: 1,1,1,1
            pos: 0, 200
            Label:
                id: answerlabel
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                text: root.thedrill.answer
        Button:
            text: 'Start'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            on_release: root.startdrill()
        Button:
            text: 'Back'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'x':0.5}
```

This gives me an error `AttributeError: 'DrillScreen' object has no attribute 'thedrill'`. If I change `root.thedrill.answer` in the label text to some literal string, it runs fine, and from the output of `printtest()` I see that it does get changed internally, but its display does not update. I'd like to either access the class attribute from the .kv file, or set the label display from the .py file. Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Proceeding upon Yoav Glazner's advice, I tried adding a button to also bind to the `printtest()` function to see what's going on, and I'm baffled to see that the calls from different bindings produce different output. Here's the modified class from the .py:

```
class DrillScreen(Screen):
    answer = StringProperty('alo')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.thedrill = drill(kwargs['options'])
        self.thedrill.bind(on_answer = self.printtest)
        super(DrillScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.answer = self.thedrill.answer

        b = Button(text = 'Test',
            size_hint = [0.1,0.1],
            pos_hint = {'top':1,'right':1})
        b.bind(on_release = self.printtest)

        self.ids.wheelbox.add_widget(b)

    def printtest(self,*args):
        self.answer = self.thedrill.answer
        print('This is printtest(): ', self.ids.answerlabel.text)

    def startdrill(self):
        Process(target=self.thedrill.run).start()
```

The only change to the .kv file is that the label text points to `root.answer`. When I run this, (and click the button in the .kv which calls `startdrill()`), `thedrill` dispatches its `on_answer` events at regular intervals, and I also click the newly created button to manually call `printtest` as well, producing such output in the terminal:

```
('This is printtest(): ', 'ti')
('This is printtest(): ', 're')
('This is printtest(): ', 'Default')
('This is printtest(): ', 'Default')
('This is printtest(): ', 'so')
('This is printtest(): ', 'Default')
('This is printtest(): ', 'le')
('This is printtest(): ', 'Default')
```

The lines with syllables are results of `on_answer` dispatches of `thedrill`, and the ones with 'Default' are from button clicks. I can't imagine what could effect the difference. On inspecting the `drill` class I see no reason for it to revert to a previous value immediately (it actually does `sleep(1)` on the line following the lines setting `.answer` and dispatching the event). Perhaps I'm missing something and I can post the code if no more plausible explanation exists.

**EDIT2:**
Here's a runnable example.
The .kv file:

```
<DrillScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            id: wheelbox
            size_hint: 1.0, None
            height: self.width
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
            background_color: 1,1,1,1
            pos: 0, 200
            Label:
                id: answerlabel
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                text: root.answer
        Button:
            text: 'Start'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            on_release: root.startdrill()
```

and the .py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from random import choice
from time import sleep
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from multiprocessing import Process

class DrillScreen(Screen):
    answer = StringProperty('Initialized.')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.thedrill = drill()
        self.thedrill.bind(on_answer = self.printtest)
        super(DrillScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.answer = self.thedrill.answer

        b = Button(
                text = 'printtest()',
                size_hint = [ 0.1, 0.1 ],
                pos_hint = {'center_x':0.75,'center_y':0.5},
                )
        b.bind(on_release = self.printtest)
        print(self.ids)
        self.ids.wheelbox.add_widget(b)

    def printtest(self,*args):
        self.answer = self.thedrill.answer
        print('This is printtest(): ', self.ids.answerlabel.text)

    def startdrill(self):
        Process(target=self.thedrill.run).start()

class drill(EventDispatcher):
    def __init__(self):
        self.register_event_type('on_answer')
        self.answer = 'Default'

    def on_answer(self,*args):
        pass

    def run(self):

        while True:

            self.answer = str(choice(range(100)))
            self.dispatch('on_answer', self.answer)
            sleep(1)

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class TestingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = Manager()
        s = DrillScreen(name='ds')
        sm.add_widget(s)
        sm.current = 'ds'
        return sm

TestingApp().run()
```

Clicking the Start button starts thedrill.run in its own process, spitting random numbers to the terminal every second, and while it is running, clicking the printtest() button outputs 'Default' as the label text value. Sample output:

```
('This is printtest(): ', '8')
('This is printtest(): ', '60')
('This is printtest(): ', '6')
('This is printtest(): ', 'Default')
('This is printtest(): ', '66')
('This is printtest(): ', '68')
('This is printtest(): ', 'Default')
('This is printtest(): ', '89')
('This is printtest(): ', '69')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order in your **__init__** function:

```
thedrill = ObjectProperty(None) # not really needed ... 

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.thedrill = drill(kwargs['options'])
    self.thedrill.bind(on_answer = self.printtest)
    super(DrillScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs) # this will trigger the kv file section that exploded before ...
```

That said, using **processes** will not work with your example since each process has its memory and cannot handle **the UI** directly. You should use a **process queue** or move to threads. just remember to update the **UI** from the main thread. (using **Clock** or **@mainthread**)

Have fun ...

Comment: The `has no attribute` complaint is gone, but the label in appearance still doesn't update even when the `printtest()` statement prints correct values to the terminal. I also tried working with `answer = StringProperty('')`, giving the label `root.answer` and in the `printtest` definition setting `self.answer` directly. It just starts out with whatever I initialize `answer` with and never changes. Also, if I initialize it to, say 'test' before `def __init__`, but set `self.answer = self.thedrill.answer` inside before `super`, it gets set correctly. The same statement fails inside `printtest`.

Comment: Galazner I included one. I suspect this has to do with `thedrill.run` running in a separate process, but I'm not competent enough to figure out how.

Comment: Yea... you can't update the UI from a different process... you must pass the data via a Queue/Pipe to the main thread/process ...

Comment: Turns out using threading instead of multiprocessing takes care of this. If you mention this in your answer in an edit I'll accept it.